# How to avoid ANR occured in android?

Tags: android

I am making an application in Android 1.6, there is an 'Application Not Responding' (ANR) error occuring - please suggest how to handle it in activity?

I did only calling of web services according to condition and used a timer which runs and calls a particular webservice. One webservice fetches users who show on a gridview, when we click on the gridview seldom ANR occured but not each time.

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` for your webservice related task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is AsyncTask. Check this short tutorial [www.vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of long-running operation, including web service access, should be done in a background thread. [Read this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).